# What's wrong with this while loop index definition?

Tags: recursion

```
For[k = 1, k < 4, k++,
 T = Table[i^2, {i, 0, k}];
 f[k] = T;
 ]
```

In the above, I wish to define a function $f$ by $f(k)=\{0^2,...,k^2\}$ for $k=1,2,3$, but the above doesn't work.

What is wrong with this? I feel as if I don't really understand while loops properly.

Comment: Why are u running `i` from `0` to $k^2$  in `T`, shouldn't it be upto `k` `T = Table[i^2, {i, 0, k}]`. Then it works. You get `f[1]` to be `{0, 1}`, `f[2]` to be `{0, 1,4}` and so on which is what you are expecting it to do right.

Comment: Oh right, fine. Yes. Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T[k]` is not the same as `T[[k]]`, the first is called indexed variable. The second is the normal list. (called array also in other languages).

Your loop does create indexed variables.

```
Clear[k, T0, f];
For[k = 1, k < 4, k++,
 T0 = Table[i^2, {i, 0, k^2}];
 f[k] = T0
 ]
```

Now type `f[1]` or `f[2]` or `f[3]` and you'll see the data there.

If you want to create a list, you can do

```
Table[i^2, {i, 0, #^2}] & /@ Range[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know of any introductory book to mathematica that covers these sort of things (the documentation sometimes is hard to use to answer questions like these).

Comment: Also, why did my code not work? Did I just forget to clear things at the start?

Comment: @Alyosha your code works. It makes indexed variables. Not a list. List uses `[[`  and indexed variables use `[`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `For`-loop. And you need to learn how functions are defined in *Mathematica*.

```
f[k_] := Table[i^2, {i, 0, k}]
```

Note `k` not `k^2` in the index specification.

To get all three lists for `k = 1, 2, 3`,

```
f /@ Range[3]
```

> `{{0, 1}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 1, 4, 9}}`

To get the list for a single value of `k`

```
f[5]
```

> `{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25}`

Comment: I should have specified that the thing in my question was just a toy example. I don't care about that particular $f$ and know how to construct it anyway. +1 regardless though, thanks.